# How to pass multiple output from function into cell array

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a function with the following prototype

```
function [bandwidth,density,X,Y,x,y]=kde2d(data,n,MIN_XY,MAX_XY)
```

basically the function returns 6 outputs as above, some are in vector form while others are a numerical quantity. How can I elegantly pass the output from the function into a 1 by 6 cell array?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

how about

```
[a{1:6}] = kde2d( data, n, MIN_XY, MAX_XY )
```

**Edit**:

consider this annoying function

```py
def foo(n):
  if n == 1:
    return [1, ]
  elif n == 2:
    return [1, ], {'a': 2}
  elif n == 3:
    return [1, ], {'a': 2}, (3, 3, 3)
  return [1, ], {'a': 2}, (3, 3, 3), None
```

You can always get all the outputs into a single tuple:

```py
for i in range(1, 5):
  f = foo(i)
  print('got {} outputs: {}'.format(len(f), f))
```

and the output of this simple loop would be:

> ```
> got 1 outputs: [1]
> got 2 outputs: ([1], {'a': 2})
> got 3 outputs: ([1], {'a': 2}, (3, 3, 3))
> got 4 outputs: ([1], {'a': 2}, (3, 3, 3), None)
> ```

If you want to get a specific output:

```py
f = foo(2)
f[1]   # accessing the second output, {'a': 2} in this example.
```

Comment: What if we don't know the number of the function's output?

Comment: @HosseinRahimi I think you can simply get the output into a single variable and then query its `len`

Comment: Assume we have a function named [out1, out2, out3, ...] =  foo(). foo() could have any number of outputs from 1 to 10 (based on the input and the nargout). What I need to get all of the available outputs of the function, regardless of the input or.

Comment: For instance, with the method that you mentioned above, we have 3 possible scenarios,
1. if nargout==6: we get the first 6 outputs of out function
2. if nargout<6: we get an error saying not enough argout
3. if nargout>6: we won't get all of the outputs

(nargout: number of arg out)