# get all output from function into cell array

Tags: matlab

some function has arbitrary number of input and output. Lets look at `ndgrid` for example: you can give N inputs, and get N outputs.

```
v={1:10,2:20,3:30...}
[d0,d1,...]=ndgrid(v{:});
```

is there's anyway to get all outputs into a cell array, e.g.

```
[d{:}]=ndgrid(v{:});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple output from function into cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523851/how-to-pass-multiple-output-from-function-into-cell-array)

Comment: Almost. In this case, the number of output arguments is unknown

Comment: If the number of outputs is unknown, this is not possible. Your answer assumes a given number of outputs. Your answer is essentially the same as the answer in the linked question. Replace `6` there with `length(v)` here.

Answer (score 0):

for future reference, yes:

```
v={1:10,2:20,3:30...}
d=cell(length(v),1);
[d{:}]=ndgrid(v{:});
```

Comment: This assumes the number of inputs is the same as the number of outputs... Might want to initialise `d` to be a size independent of `v`