# All possible combinations of many parameters MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a list of parameters and I need to evaluate my method over this list. Right now, I am doing it this way

```
% Parameters
params.corrAs = {'objective', 'constraint'};
params.size = {'small', 'medium', 'large'};
params.density = {'uniform', 'non-uniform'};
params.k = {3,4,5,6};
params.constraintP = {'identity', 'none'};
params.Npoints_perJ = {2, 3};
params.sampling = {'hks', 'fps'};   

% Select the current parameter
for corrAs_iter = params.corrAs
    for size_iter = params.size
        for density_iter = params.density
            for k_iter = params.k
                for constraintP_iter = params.constraintP
                    for Npoints_perJ_iter = params.Npoints_perJ
                        for sampling_iter = params.sampling
                            currentParam.corrAs = corrAs_iter;
                            currentParam.size = size_iter;
                            currentParam.density = density_iter;
                            currentParam.k = k_iter;
                            currentParam.constraintP = constraintP_iter;
                            currentParam.Npoints_perJ = Npoints_perJ_iter;
                            currentParam.sampling = sampling_iter;
                            evaluateMethod(currentParam);
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I know it looks ugly and if I want to add a new type of parameter, I have to write another for loop. Is there any way, I can vectorize this? Or maybe use 2 for loops instead of so many.

I tried the following but, it doesn't result in what I need.

```
for i = 1:numel(fields)
%     if isempty(params.(fields{i}))
    param.(fields{i}) = params.(fields{i})(1);
    params.(fields{i})(1) = [];
end
```

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question as posed, the concept in this question may help with your underlying problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is [all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895335/generate-a-matrix-containing-all-combinations-of-elements-taken-from-n-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1) of your input parameters. Unfortunately, as you add more parameters the storage requirements will grow quickly (and you'll have to use a large indexing matrix).

Instead, here is an idea which uses linear indicies of a (never created) `n1*n2*...*nm` matrix, where `ni` is the number of elements in each field, for `m` fields.

It is flexible enough to cope with any amount of fields being added to `params`. Not performance tested, although as with any "all combinations" operation you should be wary of the non-linear increase in computation time as you add more fields to `params`, note `prod(sz)`!

The code I've shown is fast, but the performance will depend entirely on which operations you do in the loop.

```
% Add parameters here
params.corrAs = {'objective', 'constraint'};
params.size = {'small', 'medium', 'large'};
params.density = {'uniform', 'non-uniform'};

% Setup
f = fieldnames( params );
nf = numel(f);
sz = NaN( nf, 1 );

% Loop over all parameters to get sizes
for jj = 1:nf
    sz(jj) = numel( params.(f{jj}) );
end

% Loop for every combination of parameters
idx = cell(1,nf);
for ii = 1:prod(sz)
    % Use ind2sub to switch from a linear index to the combination set
    [idx{:}] = ind2sub( sz, ii );
    % Create currentParam from the combination indices
    currentParam = struct();
    for jj = 1:nf
        currentParam.(f{jj}) = params.(f{jj}){idx{jj}};
    end
    % Do something with currentParam here
    % ...
end
```

Asides:

- I'm using [dynamic field name references](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) for indexing the fields
- I'm passing [multiple outputs into a cell array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523851/how-to-pass-multiple-output-from-function-into-cell-array) from `ind2sub`, so you can handle a variable number of field names when `ind2sub` has one output for each dimension (or field in this use-case).

Comment: Thank you, Is there a possibility to incorporate conditional fields. For example, 
    if strcmp(currentParam.corrAs, 'objective')
        currentParam.lambda = 100; % But, from params.lambda = {1, 10, 100, 1000};
    end

Comment: @zee that's a bit unclear, perhaps you could ask a new question with your desired output

Comment: please find the follow-up question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/54098049/5984672

Answer (score 3):

Here is a vectorized solution :

```
names = fieldnames(params).';
paramGrid = cell(1,numel(names));

cp = struct2cell(params);

[paramGrid{:}] = ndgrid(cp{:});

ng = [names;paramGrid];
st = struct(ng{:});


for param = st(:).'
    currentParam = param;
end
```

Instead of nested loops we can use [`ndgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to create the cartesian product of the cell entries so we can find all combinations of cell entries without loop.